# adListener adMob onDismissScreen

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I have 2 different ads in my app, a normal banner (320x50) and an interstitial ad.
When a user touches the banner, I capture this event using an adListener->onDismissScreen.

But this doesn't seem to work with the interstitial ad.
Is there a way to do the same with the interstitial ad? I just want to know if the user clicked the ad or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AdListener works the same for Interstitials as it does for banners.  Just make sure to call `interstitial.setAdListener(this);` to register for these events.

Also note that `onDismissScreen`is called when the user returns to the app after clicking your add.  `onPresentScreen` gets called right when the user clicks your ad and before the user is directed to a mobile browser or the play store.